# How to use Android methods in LibGdx core

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I created an application based on the library libgdx. As a result, I got a few projects (android, html, ios, desctop, and core). The final program is written for Android. How do I call a method from the Android project, for example, when I click on actor will be called the method who writes anything in the database or writes something in log.

Android project:
Example

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
/*example method*/
public void LogU()
  { 
    Log.e("im there","yea");
  }
}
```

}

Core project:

```
public class GameHostScreen implements Screen {

class GoToMenuListener extends ClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //need to call LogU() here
        }
    }
}
```

Sry for my bad english

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the best answer:
[Creating callback](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code)

As an example Create an interface in the core project

```
public interface IMainActivity {
  void showMainPanel();

  void showScorePanel(int score);

  void hideUi();
}
```

Then implement your activity with that interface and call that interface from your core project

In android project:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IMainActivity
```

In core project:

```
private IMainActivity context;

public DoodleJump(IMainActivity context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```